# Regex to match digit to letter transition so i can put space between them

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Is there a way to build a regex to match a digit to letter transition for e.g.:

```
e2, s5, c8
```

I have a .net application that opens a file content into a richtextbox, I want this application to find a transition from digit to letter and separate letter and digit with a white space.

Comment: So you want to turn `"e2 ,s5,c8"` into `"e2 s5 c8"`?

Comment: do you need something like "e 2, s 5, c 8" ?

Comment: If you want help you should answer to the comments and post a sample of the string you want to match, otherwise it's difficult to help you.

Comment: Can you tell us what the expected result should be instead of forcing us to speculate? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string resultString = null;
try {
    resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, @"(\d{1})([:alpha:]{1})", "$1 $2", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

Comment: OP is asking for digit to letter transition, not letter to digit.

Comment: I've corrected the regex. I was mislead by the ex (e2 ,s5,c8).

Comment: .NET regexes don't support the POSIX character classes (`[:alpha:]`, `[:digit:]`, etc.).  It looks like you wrote that regex in RegexBuddy; the reason RB didn't complain is because because you got the syntax wrong, too--it should have been `[[:alpha:]]`.  In every flavor I know of, `[:alpha:]` on its own is just another character set, equivalent to `[ahlp:]`.

Comment: One more thing: please don't use the "quantifier" `{1}`.  All you're doing is cluttering up your regex, telling it to do what it was going to do anyway, i.e., match one of the preceding atom.

Answer (score 0):

MATCH ANY:

e2, s5, c8

REGEX:

([a-z])
(\d)
,

OR:

([a-z])(\d),

Group1 is letters, group2 is numbers, rebuild string with group1 + " " + group2, to give:
e 2 , s 5, c 8

Test here:
http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

Comment: thank youu,it was really helpful  ,i had to change it to (\d)([a-z]) to get the needed result,but it's the same

Comment: glad it helped, dont forget to marked as answer and vote up ;)